# macros on document open. Bug in ms office 2013?

Tags: vba, ms-office

I have a macros that starts running when a document opens. It looks like this:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

   ....
   Dim strInput As String
   strInput = ActiveDocument.Content
   ....
```

In office 2010 this macros works nicely, however, in office 2013 I get this error message (translation to English):

> This command is not available, because there are no documents opened

And when I hit on Debug button, I see that this line of code is highligthed:

```
strInput = ActiveDocument.Content
```

I think it's a bug of office 2013, because for some insane reason it invokes this macros before the document is opened, even though I clearly force it to do right after opening - `Private Sub Document_Open()`. So, what is wrong with that and how can I fix that?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a43d59d6-d4f8-46c7-90e6-0ff6782f58d6/word-2013-this-method-or-property-is-not-available-because-this-command-is-not-available-for-reading?forum=worddev

Comment: Judging by this ^^^ it is indeed ms office bug.

Comment: It seems like when I open the document in office 2013, it is not yet in editable mode (there is a yellow ribbon at the top saying that I'm in secure mode), but still office invokes my macros, that requires the document to be editable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing the yellow message bar then this isn't a bug. It's because your document isn't "trusted" - it's "sandboxed". You need to check whether it's a ProtectedViewWindow - introduced in Office 2010 - and take appropriate action.

The Protected View is explained in this article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-Protected-View-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653. Basically, it prevents code from running in any document that comes from an origin / author that isn't trusted. The user needs to make an explicit decision to trust the document in order to go into Edit mode.

Obviously, this is a major impediment to VBA code, so you have the ProtectedViewWindow object in the object model. There are application-level events that can be used to manage this state in the entire Word environment, such as ProtectedViewWindowOpen that triggers when a document is opened "sandboxed". After determining whether the document is trustworthy, the code can make the document editable using the ProtectedViewWindow.Edit method.

For example, to trust all documents that come from a specific file path:

```
Private Sub app_ProtectedViewWindowOpen(ByVal PvWindow _
            As ProtectedViewWindow)
  If PvWindow.SourcePath = "C:\Test" Then
    PvWindow.Edit
  End If
End Sub
```

The above needs to be in an application-level class module and events for this class need to be active on the application. If you're not familiar with using application-level events, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821218.aspx

Comment: "Basically, it prevents code from running in any document that comes from an origin / author that isn't trusted.". So, if it is not trusted, until the user agrees, why does it still run a macro that causes this error message "This command is not available, because there are no documents opened"?

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted the yellow message you're seeing. What does it say, EXACTLY? And does the code I suggest work in that scenario?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact translation (because it's not English version of the office), but as far as I can gather it says that "you are in a safe mode (or view). Enable editing?"

Comment: Besides, its says "Be carefull, because Internet files may be malicious. If you do not want to edit this file you can continue working in a safe mode". Something like that.